# Kohana 3.3 $_has_many error

Tags: php, orm, kohana, has-many, has-one

I'm trying to setup a one-to-many relationship between a User and his Clients. I can access a single client when I set my model like this:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {
    protected $_has_one = array(
        'client' => array(
            'model' => 'Client',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_id')
    );
    [...]
```

But when I try to switch to $_has_many:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'clients' => array(
            'model' => 'Client',
            'foreign_key' => 'user_id')
    );
    [...]
```

I get the following error:

```
Database_Exception [ 1103 ]: Incorrect table name '' [ SELECT COUNT(*) AS `records_found` FROM `` WHERE = '74' AND IN ('4') ]
```

Can't figure out what's wrong..

Comment: What's the SQL query your executing here? The one that's in the error message doesn't look like right.

Comment: i fell you have something wrong in client model. can you add your client model ?

Comment: My Client model is pretty basic:

Comment: class Model_Client extends ORM {
 protected $_belongs_to = array('user' => array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 'user_id'));
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
Declaring the $_has_many property in my User model was overwriting the same property in Kohana source file, which contained roles and tokens information.

Solved by copying the values from Kohana's Model_Auth_User and adding my property:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'user_tokens' => array('model' => 'User_Token'),
    'roles'       => array('model' => 'Role', 'through' => 'roles_users'),
    'clients'     => array('model' => 'Client', 'foreign_key' => 'user_id'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How does it look in the Client? If you have "Client -> has_one -> User", this shouldn't be a problem.

If you have "Client -> has_many -> User", you need [has_many through](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through)